# box-shadow to the left side of a div only

Tags: css

Alright, I know that this question has been asked before, but I have a kind of different CSS and the effect is different too. My CSS:

```
div.side-bar {
    text-align: right;
    width: 11%;
    margin-left: 88%;
    border-left: 1px solid #000;
    position: fixed;
    height: 88%;
    -webkit-box-shadow: -5px 0px 5px 0px #616161;
    box-shadow: -5px 0px 5px 0px #616161;
}
```

So using the following code gives me a shadow to the left side as I wanted, but it also adds small shadows to both top and bottom sides too. How to have a shadow only on the left side?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try changing your box-shadow property by adding a negative spread radius like this: http://jsfiddle.net/vW8VS/3/

```
div.side-bar {
    text-align: right;
    width: 11%;
    margin-left: 88%;
    border-left: 1px solid #000;
    position: fixed;
    height: 88%;
    -webkit-box-shadow: -5px 0px 5px -3px #616161;
    box-shadow: -5px 0px 5px -3px #616161;
}
```

That should let you push it off to just one side without worrying about the top and bottom.

Answer (score 1):

I found to get the proper box-shadow effect to the left side of a div only I had to play around more with the css. use the below styles, they worked great for what I was trying to achieve.

```
-webkit-box-shadow: -35px 0px 20px -35px #aaa;
box-shadow: -35px 0px 20px -35px #aaa;
```